# Move child divs in a table while scrolling horizontaly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've came accross a weird problem...

I have a parent relative div with a large table. Then I append a random number of absolute divs to this parent. Each has a different width and its starting position is based on certain cell in the table. Basic layout looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="1"></td>
      <td id="2"></td>
      <td id="3"></td>
      <td id="4"></td>
      <td id="5"></td>
      <td id="6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="7"></td>
      <td id="8"></td>
      <td id="9"></td>
      <td id="10"></td>
      <td id="11"></td>
      <td id="12"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I then use jQuery to append new divs to the container, like this:

```
$("#container").append("<div id='uniqueId' class='someClass'></div>");
$("#uniqueId").css({    
    "left" : $("#cell_3").position().left,
    "top" :  $("#cell_3").position().top
})
```

New divs have position: absolute; assigned. Container div has a horizontal scroll bar, and when I move scroll bar to the right, absolute divs stay at their positions and scroll along. I would like them to stick to their starting table cells and move to the left, when I move scroll bar to the right.

Temporary fix was, I manualy assigned each of them their starting position (cell id) and used:

```
$("#container").scroll(function () {
    $("#uniqueId").css({
        "left" : $("#cell_3").position().left
    });
}
```

But there has to be better solution to target them all at once. I am also planning on making them draggable and resizable; in that case my solution would get very messy. Any ideas?

EDIT:
As far as "child divs not moving while scrolling horizontaly" problem, I found out I made a typo when coding my original css.

```
#container { position: relative; }
```

This solved my problem (originaly I misstyped relative). Any other position or no declaration of position at all for #container would result in appended absolute `<div>` to stay in place instead of scroll like other content.

I kindly thank to everyone for a brain storm, forcing me to go through my code again.

Comment: Does `#container` have a position assigned to it?

Comment: position: absolute has that attribute to not move on the screen (including scrolling).  Have you tried relative or another position attribute?

Comment: @JoePacker That is incorrect. `position:fixed` does not move with scrolling. However, if `#container` is relative while the `#uniqueId`s are absolute, then yes they will not move with the relative element's scrolling.

Comment: @imtheman Yes, relative.

I need a neat jquery code that will apply my solution to all children divs (`#uniqueId`s) inside `#container`. My code gets too messy and will be useless if I change `#uniqueId`s to draggable or resizable

Comment: @Blaz Can you not make the `#uniqueId`s relative as JoePacker suggests?

Comment: Are the random divs larger or smaller than the table tds?

Comment: @imtherman Positioning becomes a real pain if I change them to relative :( I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: @TimSPQR They are equal or larger than table tds, never smaller

Comment: I found original source of my problem: I made a typo when coding css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question, so I thought I'd take a stab at it and perhaps learn a bit.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/842y93yv/1/) with a preliminary result.

Assumptions:

1. table with two rows of 6 tds each
2. little boxes are associated with tds randomly and are positioned in the upper left-hand corner of the td.

Workings:

1. Create an array of all of the upper-left coordinates of each of the tds in the table.
2. Create an array of random yes/no for each of the tds which will determine if a box will be placed there.
3. Loop through each of the tds and determine if a box should be associated with that td, and then if 'yes', use the appropriate coordinates for that box - if 'no', do nothing.

The boxes can be moved around by offsetting the coordinates deterministically or randomly.

The box sizes and/or background colors could be changed randomly.

It would be interesting to hear if this is a start at what you're looking for.

JS

```
var tdarray = [];
$('#container table tr td').each(function(index){
  tdarray[index] = $(this).position().left;
  tdarray[index+12] = $(this).position().top;
                                                 });

var whichboxes = [];
for(r=0; r < 12; r++)
   {
    if( Math.random() >= 0.5 )
      {
       whichboxes[r] = 1;
       }
    else
     {
      whichboxes[r] = 0;
      }
   }
$('.putmehere2').html( "Boxes to place: " + whichboxes );

for(var n = 0; n < 12; n++)
{
  if( whichboxes[n] == 1 )
    {
     var leftcoord = tdarray[n];
     var topcoord  = tdarray[n+12];
     $("#container").append("<div class='randomdiv' id='box" + n + "'></div>");
     $( "#box" + n ).css({    
                         "left" : leftcoord,
                         "top" :  topcoord
                          });
     }
    else
    {
       var donothing = 0;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution of placing random divs. You also forced me to go through my code again and find out I made a stupid mistake while typing my original css. `#container` had `position: relaitve; instead of `position: relative` :( Typo was a source of my problem of divs not moving while scrolling. Changinm that, all works flawlessly. I will use your code to place divs and add random width to `$( "#box" + n ).css()`